# React - can't dispatch action in hook component

Tags: react-redux, react-hooks

Using dispatch in useffect hook of functional component,
Below code shows error page like below;
[image]

Component:

```
  import { GetParks } from "../../../redux/actions/survey_actions"
...
function BarcodeGenerator(props) {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(props.GetParks());
  }, []);
```

actions:

```
export const GetParks = (Id) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  try {
    const response = await axiosHelper.get("api/survey/GetParks", {
      params: {
        Id,
      },
    });
    debugger;
    response = response.data;
    if (response.status !== ResponseStatus.SUCCESS) {
      dispatch({
        type: GET_PARKS,
        payload: [1, 4555, 34],
      });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    catchCallback(error);
  }
};

const _getParks = (data) => ({
  type: GET_PARKS,
  payload: data,
});
```

how does dispatch the action to reducer properly

Answer (score 0):

Action must be a plain object, as it is described in the error description. E.g. it is ok to use dispatch directly as is:

```
if (*statement*) {
  dispatch({
    action: DO_SMTH,
    payload: true
  })
}
```

or to make the action creator returning the equal object if you want to make clean re-usable code:

```
if (*statement*) {
  dispatch(doSmth(true));
}
function doSmth(toggle) {
  return ({
    action: DO_SMTH,
    payload: toggle
  })
}
```

Comment: The whole process involves dispatch, action, reducer, store. It is impossible to say what is going wrong without having all the picture visible. Try to re-build the working example showing the problem with jsfiddle or any other playground.